# C# how to use async and await?

Tags: c#, winforms, async-await, serial-port

I make serial communication method. it return receive message

first, button click

```
List<string> SendPkt = new List<string>();
List<string> RecvPkt = new List<string>();

private void btnRead_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SendPkt.Clear();
    RecvPkt.Clear();

    C_Serial c_serial = new C_Serial();

    Trace.WriteLine("start : "+DateTime.Now);

    RecvPkt = c_serial.CommunicationJob(Port, Baud, SendPkt);

    for (int i = 0; i < RecvPkt.Count; i++)
        Trace.WriteLine(RecvPkt[i]);

    Trace.WriteLine("end : "+DateTime.Now);
}
```

and C_Serial is...

```
public List<string> CommunicationJob(string port, int boud, List<string> sendPkt)
{
    string openResult = OpenPort(port, boud);
    string recvMsg = "";
    ....
    List<string> recvs = new List<string>();

    for (int i = 0; i < sendPkt.Count; i++)
    {
        recvMsg = SendAndRecv(sendPkt[i]);
        Trace.WriteLine("recvMsg : " + recvMsg);
        recvs.Add(recvMsg);
    }

    return recvs;
}
...
public string SendAndRecv(string sendPkt)
{
    string recvPkt = "";
    serialWrite(sendPkt);
    recvPkt = waitDataReceived();
    return recvPkt;
}

...

private string waitDataReceived()
{
    while(true)
    {
        // check about message recv complete
    }
}
```

waitDataReceived() has infinity loop so it must work as thread

So I make SendAndRecv() like that

```
public string SendAndRecv(string sendPkt)
{
    string recvPkt = "";
    serialWrite(sendPkt);
    Thread th = new Thread(() => recvPkt = waitDataReceived());
    th.Start();
    th.Join();
    return recvPkt;
}
```

but Join() is block UI when infinity loop.

I search about that and I find async/await.

So I modified SendAndRecv()

```
public async Task<string> SendAndRecv(string sendPkt)
{
    string recvs = "";
    serialWrite(sendPkt);   
    recvs = await Task.Run(() => waitDataReceived());
    return recvs;
}
```

And It use in CommunicationJob() like this

```
recvMsg = SendAndRecv(sendPkt[i]).Result;
```

But it still blocks the UI. Even if the infinite loop breaks, it is not released.

And don't print recvMsg in CommunicationJob().

Program is stop.

How can I use thread not block UI and wait until return value?

Comment: It is the call to `.Result` that blocks. That makes all the async stuff useless. A baseline "rule" in using async/await is "Go async all the way" (of course there are exceptions, but ... ). But anyway I'd suggest you smart up on threading, concurrency and adjacend topics, first.

Comment: nice question, very informative and good structured! deserves more upvotes in my opinion

Comment: The ComPort is event driven, async/await is not going to be the magic solution here.  I am very suspicious about that `waitDataReceived()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to buble up the pattern until your GUI click method. In the line of succession (calling hierarchy) **every method** has to be async and use await

```
public async Task<List<string>> CommunicationJob(string port, int boud, List<string> sendPkt)
{
    string openResult = OpenPort(port, boud);
    string recvMsg = "";
    ....
    List<string> recvs = new List<string>();

    for (int i = 0; i < sendPkt.Count; i++)
    {
        recvMsg = await SendAndRecv(sendPkt[i]);
        Trace.WriteLine("recvMsg : " + recvMsg);
        recvs.Add(recvMsg);
    }

    return recvs;
}

private async void btnRead_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SendPkt.Clear();
    RecvPkt.Clear();

    C_Serial c_serial = new C_Serial();

    Trace.WriteLine("start : "+DateTime.Now);

    RecvPkt = await c_serial.CommunicationJob(Port, Baud, SendPkt);

    for (int i = 0; i < RecvPkt.Count; i++)
        Trace.WriteLine(RecvPkt[i]);

    Trace.WriteLine("end : "+DateTime.Now);
}
```

This should ensure that the UI does not freeze.

You could actually write the await directly after the `return` statement:

```
public async Task<string> SendAndRecv(string sendPkt)
{
    string recvs = "";
    serialWrite(sendPkt);
    return await Task.Run(() => waitDataReceived());;
}
```

Comment: Yes. But please note that `async void` should only be used for event handlers, and it is a good idea to always put a try/catch inside them.

Answer (score 1):

Not only do you have to make `SendAndRecv` async, you also have to make all its callers, and the callers of those callers (and so on) `async`. And when you call an `async` method, you use `await`.

Therefore, `CommunicationJob` should be `async`

```
public async Task<List<string>> CommunicationJob(string port, int boud, List<string> sendPkt)
{
    string openResult = OpenPort(port, boud);
    string recvMsg = "";
    ....
    List<string> recvs = new List<string>();

    for (int i = 0; i < sendPkt.Count; i++)
    {
        recvMsg = await SendAndRecv(sendPkt[i]); // <--- note this line!
        Trace.WriteLine("recvMsg : " + recvMsg);
        recvs.Add(recvMsg);
    }

    return recvs;
}
```

And `btnRead_Click` should be `async`

```
private async void btnRead_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SendPkt.Clear();
    RecvPkt.Clear();

    C_Serial c_serial = new C_Serial();

    Trace.WriteLine("start : "+DateTime.Now);

    RecvPkt = await c_serial.CommunicationJob(Port, Baud, SendPkt);

    for (int i = 0; i < RecvPkt.Count; i++)
        Trace.WriteLine(RecvPkt[i]);

    Trace.WriteLine("end : "+DateTime.Now);
}
```

Comment: I don't think `async Task btnRead_Click` can be clicked.